# Transfer books in iBooks from my iPad3 to iTunes

Tags: itunes, ipad

I lost my original hard drive, and I have some books (in ePub format, I believe) on my iPad 3 that have bookmarks and highlighted stuff which I'd like to preserve.

Is there *any* way to get that info back to my iTunes? I did not purchase them through iBooks or iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't buy the books via iTunes or iBooks, the files are preserved only in your backups, and as far as I'm aware, there isn't a supported way to recover them back to iTunes.

If you were to jailbreak the device, you could go on a fishing expedition, but I doubt what you're looking for is possible.

Comment: they were not purchases

Comment: I've rewritten my answer based on this new information, and updated your question to reflect this.